# Debugging Javascript for beginners

Tags: jquery, debugging

I have this script that I cannot debug by trial and error. What is the preferred EASY way to debug javascript? How do I track down bugs using Firebug as easily as I use Firebug for css debuging?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/72QPC/5/

```
var options1 = {
  valueNames: [ 'filterUrgency', 'filterType', 'ID', 'Type', 'Task', 'Project', 'Status', 'DueDate', 'Region', 'Market', 'Title', 'Author', 'Published' ]
};

//sorter 1 ---------------------------------------------
var sortedList1 = new List('sorter-1', options1);

//sorter 2 ---------------------------------------------
var sortedList2 = new List('sorter-2', options1);
```

Comment: `List` is undefined in your example above. But this isn't really the type of question for SO - google is your best friend.

Comment: It's pretty simple. There is no `List` constructor, so you're getting a reference error when you're trying to construct from it. Did you forget to import a library or something?

Comment: First look at the console. Did you notice this? `Uncaught ReferenceError: List is not defined ` that means the `List` class is not defined. More than likely that is related to one of the 404's that happend before that console message.

Comment: Ok thanks. I see now in Console/Script that I have this error:  a.values()[value] is undefined on line 282 of the plugin. I suppose that means I do not have a variable in my script defined?

Comment: @simple When an error occurs within a plug-in, that can mean that you're using it incorrectly. Well, either that or it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by opening the "Console" tab of Firebug to check if any errors were thrown.

Usually, if an error occurs, you can look up in the console where it occurred (on which line), so it's trivial to find that line in your code, and then decide to set a break point somewhere before that line (if necessary.)

You can set break points in the "Script" tab. Just select the file, and click on the line number, then trigger code execution (e.g. reload the page). Execution will halt on that break point. You can then analyze the state (e.g. the values of local variables, and arguments).

Comment: Thanks. What if I choose for firebug to "break on next" (button top left in script tab)? That seems to be a good way to find the error quickly?

Comment: @simple Usually, if an error occurs, you can look up in the console where it occurred (on which line), so it's trivial to find that line in your code, and then decide to set a break point somewhere before that line (if necessary).